# Django template with 2 'inputs'

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have this simple Django view, where I can (correctly) get map coordinates (lat, lng) from the URL, and wish to pass them onto a template named 'test.html'. Right now I just pass the latitude along:

```
#views.py
...
def testview(request, lat, lng):
    return render(request, 'polls/test.html', {'lat':lat})
```

And it works fine.

My issue is how to also pass the longitude (lng) along. I have learned how to pass a solo input from the official Django documentation, but can't find any mention on how to do it for multiple inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just include it in the context dictionary like the first one:

```
def testview(request, lat, lng):
    return render(request, 'polls/test.html', {'lat':lat, 'lng': lng})
#                                                          ^^^^^^^^^
```